# SharePoint Designer Crashes When Adding a Custom Web Part

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, error, development

I'm trying to add a webpart to a "Dispform.aspx" of a list in SharePoint Designer.
I can add OOTB webparts without any problem, but mine just won't work. By the way, I can add the web part normally inside a page in IE.
Here's the code of one plain web part I tried adding (it made SPD crash) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

namespace Project.SharePoint.Internet.Base
{
    [Guid("1e9d4769-611b-4fa4-8f1c-bb54c9138233")]
    public class PlainWP : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart
    {
        private bool _error = false;
        private string _myProperty = null;

        public PlainWP()
        {
            this.ExportMode = WebPartExportMode.All;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create all your controls here for rendering.
        /// Try to avoid using the RenderWebPart() method.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            if (!_error)
            {
                try
                {

                    base.CreateChildControls();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    HandleException(ex);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ensures that the CreateChildControls() is called before events.
        /// Use CreateChildControls() to create your controls.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_error)
            {
                try
                {
                    base.OnLoad(e);
                    this.EnsureChildControls();

                    // Your code here...
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    HandleException(ex);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clear all child controls and add an error message for display.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ex"></param>
        private void HandleException(Exception ex)
        {
            this._error = true;
            this.Controls.Clear();
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(ex.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

I tried debugging the code in the Web part. When I add the Web Part in SPD, it does go to my breakpoint. The constructor is called once, then CreateChildControls, Constructor, CreateChildControls, Constructor, then crashes.

Am I missing an override or something?

Comment: Please clarify if it is SPD 2007 or SPD 2010.

Comment: SPD 2007. Like i've said, it works on another computer and I never found a solution for my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing IDesignTimeHtmlProvider as I mentioned in my blog here:  http://www.thelineberrys.com/default-category/viewing-sharepoint-webparts-in-frontpage-2.html

Also, maybe try commenting out the onload function.

Comment: The breakpoint in the IDesignTimeHtmlProvider is never called and SPD still chrases :(  I'm going to try on another server.

Comment: Is it SharePoint 2010? If so I don't think that SPD2010 uses IDesignTimeHtmlProvider, it renders the WP "for real".

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a safe control entry?

Comment: There's an entry for all the classes of the DLL yes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried your class with only a CreateChildControls? Nothing in the constructor, no exception handling, just the CreateChildControls method.